# Would the new HandOff app in iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite work on iOS 7?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, ios

First of all, I have an iPhone 4, meaning I can't upgrade anymore to iOS 8. I would really like to use the "Handoff" and I have a mac (Mid-2011). It can upgrade to Yosemite the new OS X. Can my Mac answer the calls, messages from my iPhone which has iOS 7?

Comment: Handoff is not an app, it's an operating system feature - therefore it cannot be used without both iOS 8 or later, and OS X 10.10 Yosemite or later. Also, it requires Bluetooth 4.0 LE support, which the iPhone 4 does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need both iOS 8.1 and OS X 10.10 for this to work.